# Where can I download some sample database regarding cars data?

Tags: database, prediction, sample-data

I want to apply some predictive algorithms on car data, is there any free or commercial database possible to download regarding the data that cars made?

Even the data regarding a specific part of a car is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below link which is basically give listing of vehicles and specifications.

https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/

Mainly this is in format of API but there are some options to get in XML, CSV, JSON. You can use it accordingly.

Comment: But it seems it only provide the list of errors in the cars electronic systems, and not a real data of how often these problems happen. It seems I have to create some random data, but anyway it is good data for making the defect data model. Thanks.